# Area of intersection between parabola and square

Tags: geometry

The cubic $3x^2-x^3$ divides the square with endpoints A(0,0) and B(4,0) in three parts.

How can I show that this is true and what are the areas of the parts?

What I see so far, is that the parabola has roots at x = 0 and x = 3. But how can I **prove** that it cuts the square in three pieces (and how then to calculate the areas)?

Comment: Sorry, I translated it from the german "Parabel". So in german it is still called this way.

Comment: This picture may help. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+3x%5E2%E2%88%92x%5E3%2C+x+from+0+to+4%2C+y+from+0+to+4

Answer (score 1):

**Hints** Plot the graph of the function, and draw the square. What changes when we consider $\dfrac1{10}(3x^2-x^3)$ instead?

For calculating the area, use suitably chosen integrals (this will require you to find the endpoints of the three parts).

Comment: if we multiply it by 1/10, what changes is the range of the function on the y-scale (i.e. the maxima would be lower). How does that go into the direction of a proof? thanks

Comment: There will then only remain _two_ parts...